# Remote CRUD to MariaDB using persistent SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, tunnel

Hoping someone can help me with this problem.

### My Setup

I have a Client and Server setup both running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. They are both located on different networks. I want to be able to work on the MariaDB Database which is installed on the Server while I'm on the Client computer. What I'm trying to do is setup SSH so that if I send a localhost command for a specific port (3306) on the Client computer, it gets routed to the Server and processed at the Server like it's a localhost command to the Server.

To do this I have a user added on both the Client and the Server. It's the same user and the same password for the user on both the Client and Server.

I have changed the default SSH Port on the Server to be **Port 8888** (Coz I'm not a fan of 'defaults') and I am able to SSH into the Server (from the Client computer) as this user I created just fine (Port forwarding and Routing issues are taken care of). Once connected to the Server by SSH I'm able to login to MariaDB and CRUD the database.

I found quite a few websites that claim SSH can allow me to setup a tunnel and once the tunnel is in place and command sent to a specific port can be executed at the Server. This is what is supposed to work:

```
ssh user@myserver.mycompany.com -p 8888 -L 3306:localhost:3306 -N
```

### Please note that for this discussion

- user - the username of the account that is on both the Client and Server. The only restriction for this user is that the user account is NOT in the sudoers file. The user has a home directory and everything.
- myserver.mycomany.com - is able to resolve to the IP of where the Server is located
- 8888 - the port that is routed to the Server
- 3306 - the port where MariaDB is accessible from
- MariaDB has been configured with a user/password

### The Problem

The issue I'm having is when I use the following command, the cursor just hangs after I hit enter (As though the command didn't complete) coz it doesn't bring me back to the prompt (I have to CTRL+C to break out of it) i.e. the cursor just blinks on the next line:

```
ssh user@myserver.mycompany.com -p 8888 -L 3306:localhost:3306 -N
```

If however I remove the -N from the command then the command seems to have completed successfully but I'm not able to login to MariaDB from the Client computer. So really it did nothing.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Or maybe tell me I'm crazy to try this and it's not possible?

### What I am secretly wishing

I want to be able to run this tunnel using autossh once I have figured out how to do it. Then all I have to do is login to the Client computer and run database commands which all get routed to the Server without having to do any setup.

### What I have done so far

Based on Jos's recommendation I ran

```
ssh -vv user@myserver.mycompany.com -p 8888 -L 3306:localhost:3306 -N
```

and got more info. It was hanging at

```
client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

I found somewhere that a restart of systemd-logind might fix that so I did a:

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

I got further this time and the command did exit but with a status of 127. It's a huge output but here are the last 85-ish lines starting at what looks relevant:

```
Authenticated to hiding.myservername.com ([hiding.my.ip.com]:8888).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: 3306:localhost:3306 -N
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 38
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 6/(38)
sh: 1: 3306:localhost:3306: not found
debug2: channel 0: written 38 to efd 6
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Transferred: sent 2432, received 2528 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5324.3, received 5534.5
debug1: Exit status 127
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

I forwarded the MySQL Port 3306 to the Server (though I don't think I need to since I'm hoping to go over the SSH port of 8888). I'm still stuck at.

```
client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

This time restarting systemd-logind doesn't help.

I tested the MySQL Port from the Server with

```
User@Server:~$ telnet localhost 3306
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
t
5.5.5-10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic-log$j0Mqri9!�5&`3y+fBUf"smysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.
```

Looks ok to me.

If I telnet across the network I get a 'Connection Refused' thats coz MariaDB has been configured for localhost authentication only.

Continuing this exploration.. I installed a fresh Ubuntu system on the local network where the server is located. I ran the SSH command using local ip addresses (Rather than DNS resolved hostnames) and since the 2 systems are in one subnet I have eliminated any Routing/NAT/Port Forwarding issues at the Gateway. I still have a hanging client_input_global_blablabla

I testing using a connection with the user account that is in the Sudoers file. No luck.

Next step... Reinstall the server and try this same connection without any Public Key Authentication.

Comment: Try `ssh -vv ...` to get more information about what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Jos! I didn't know ssh could output it's connection info like that. I find it gets stuck at: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0

A quick search and I find that it might get fixed with a restart of systemd-logind:
systemctl restart systemd-logind

And now I'm able to get further but SSH exits with 127.

debug3: send packet: type 1
Transferred: sent 2432, received 2528 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6588.4, received 6848.5
debug1: Exit status 127

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information to it.

Comment: Ok it's done. Not sure if that's how its supposed to be done

Comment: I notice this: `sh: 1: 3306:localhost:3306: not found`. Are you sure you used the proper syntax for this command?

Comment: I checked the syntax over a couple of times. Removed the -N switch to see if it would make a difference. Nothing. Rebooted both the client and server and went thru the process again and I'm stuck again at the client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0. Restarting systemd-logind doesn't help. I even forwarded the MySQL Port 3306 to the server (though I don't think I should have to coz I'm going over SSH).. But still stuck at the client_input_global thing